# Is it real Hadoop framework is not suitable for real-time operation?

Tags: hadoop, frameworks, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I've read in a blog and it stated that

> Hadoop is batch processing centric ideal for the discovery, exploration and analysis of large amounts of multi-structured data that doesn’t fit nicely into table, and not suitable for real-time operations.

So, anyone can help me by giving better explanation on this like whay it is not suitable for real-time operations. TQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For realtime processing you have HBase, which is part of the Hadoop ecosystem:

**http://hbase.apache.org/**

> Apache HBase is the Hadoop database, a distributed, scalable, big
>   data store.
>
> **When Would I Use Apache HBase?**
>
> Use Apache HBase when you need random, realtime read/write access to
>   your Big Data. This project's goal is the hosting of very large tables
>   -- billions of rows X millions of columns -- atop clusters of commodity hardware. Apache HBase is an open-source, distributed,
>   versioned, non-relational database modeled after Google's Bigtable: A
>   Distributed Storage System for Structured Data by Chang et al. Just as
>   Bigtable leverages the distributed data storage provided by the Google
>   File System, Apache HBase provides Bigtable-like capabilities on top
>   of Hadoop and HDFS.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Linear and modular scalability.
> - List item
> - Strictly consistent reads and writes.
> - Automatic and configurable sharding of tables
> - Automatic failover support between RegionServers.
> - Convenient base classes for backing Hadoop MapReduce jobs with Apache HBase tables.
> - Easy to use Java API for client access.
> - Block cache and Bloom Filters for real-time queries.
> - Query predicate push down via server side Filters
> - Thrift gateway and a REST-ful Web service that supports XML, Protobuf, and  binary data encoding options
> - Extensible jruby-based (JIRB) shell
> - Support for exporting metrics via the Hadoop metrics subsystem to files or  Ganglia; or via JMX

It also supports atomic counters, which is one of HBase's strongest points and can help you reducing the need of large analysis jobs (with a careful and planned row key and schema design).

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop MapReduce was not suitable for real time processing.

But now, that is changing. For e.g., [Storm](https://storm.apache.org/), [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) provides near realtime processing capabilities.

Spark uses in memory computation to enable faster processing. It uses RDD(Resilient Distributed Dataset) as memory abstraction.

Where as Storm uses DAG of spouts(sources) and bolts(sinks).This is called a topology and a topology keep running. ie., it takes data from spouts and gives to bolts.Bolts can write this data on to database or make it available to the user. This reduces processing time.